# How to fix navigation bar and move contents only while pushing controller?

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uistoryboard

I am using storyboard in my project. In that i implemented RESideMenu. Now when i click on any item from menu, it will open in navigationcontroller. In that header name is constant so i want to keep navigation bar constant and just want to move/slide contents while pushing any controller. How we can achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Can anyone help me to implement this i stuck from 2 days..

Comment: did you got solution for this?

Comment: Yes, I kept push animation as 'NO', and given custom animation to both controller.

Comment: Feel free to add an answer if you solved it ;)